# Upgrading Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have updated rails and have rails -v and it says 3.0.5. (which is good) when i open my old programs, will it still always use 3.0.4 as that is what was used?

And ..
when i create new one will it use 3.0.5

I have done this as i'm a newbie and having problems with tutorials from the rails by example book michael hartl and wondering if it is the version that is giving the problems.

Thanks for any help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Rails 3 Bundler was added to handle gem dependencies. Within each application a Gemfile exists that specifies the version of Rails to use. If you want to update an application change the version in your Gemfile and run `bundle install`.